# Ionic 3 app is slow on iOS devices: ionic cordova build ios --prod --aot

Tags: ios, cordova, typescript, ionic3

Currently, I am working on a project, which is Ionic 3. I need to deploy the app on iOS devices. But the app is very slow in iOS devices. I tried to run this cmd `ionic cordova build ios --prod --aot`. But it resulted in a bunch of Ionic components error.

Screenshot of error when taking `prod` and `aot` app build:

[image]

package.json

```
{
    "name": "Demo",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
        "serve:before": "watch",
        "emulate:before": "build",
        "deploy:before": "build",
        "build:before": "build",
        "run:before": "build",
        "test": "ng test --code-coverage",
        "e2e": "protractor",
        "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "*",
        "@ionic-native/badge": "*",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "*",
        "@ionic-native/core": "*",
        "@ionic-native/file": "*",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "*",
        "@ionic-native/file-path": "*",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "*",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "*",
        "@ionic-native/keyboard": "*",
        "@ionic-native/media": "*",
        "@ionic-native/network": "*",
        "@ionic-native/push": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "*",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "*",
        "@ionic-native/streaming-media": "*",
        "@ionic-native/transfer": "*",
        "@ionic-native/video-player": "*",
        "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "*",
        "@types/googlemaps": "*",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.92",
        "accounts-password-client-side": "*",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "*",
        "angular2-moment": "*",
        "angular2-swing": "^0.14.0",
        "aws-sdk": "*",
        "body-parser": "*",
        "braintree": "^2.4.0",
        "braintree-web": "^3.27.0",
        "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-badge": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-filepicker": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "*",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "*",
        "cors": "*",
        "express": "*",
        "intl": "*",
        "ionic-angular": "*",
        "ionic-image-loader": "git+https://github.com/patricktyndall/ionic-image-loader.git",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "*",
        "ionic2-autosize": "*",
        "ionic2-rating": "*",
        "ionicons": "*",
        "jquery": "*",
        "jssha": "^2.3.1",
        "lodash": "*",
        "meteor-rxjs": "*",
        "meteor-tracker": "*",
        "moment": "*",
        "ng2-cordova-oauth": "0.0.8",
        "ng2-currency-mask": "*",
        "ng2-translate": "*",
        "ng2-validation-manager": "^5.0.0",
        "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.1.2",
        "rxjs": "*",
        "stripe": "^5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "*",
        "underscore": "*",
        "zone.js": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.7",
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.44",
        "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
        "@types/jssha": "0.0.29",
        "@types/meteor": "^1.4.13",
        "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
        "ionic": "^3.19.0",
        "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [
        "ios",
        {
            "platform": "ios",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "ios"
        }
    ],
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filepicker": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-media": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "phonegap-plugin-push": {
                "SENDER_ID": "318310044174"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
            "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
            "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": {
                "XWALK_VERSION": "23+",
                "XWALK_LITEVERSION": "xwalk_core_library_canary:17+",
                "XWALK_COMMANDLINE": "--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect",
                "XWALK_MODE": "embedded",
                "XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK": "true"
            }
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Ionic info file:

[image]

We have tried all the existing solutions, but none of them worked.
Please help us in solving this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this problem?

If yes, then try uninstalling all plugins, cleaning your project, then reinstall all the previously removed plugins again. Make sure every plugin has the right dependencies installed (and in the right version).

Personally, I don't know if there's a quick way to uninstall/reinstall everything, but this - if not by much - may actually speed up your application run speed and possibly solve inconsistencies, so it's definitely worth trying (if you haven't already).

Hope to have helped!